# Where can I get/read SQL standard SQL:2011?

Tags: sql, standards, iso

I'm looking for specification of SQL:2011 (ISO/IEC 9075:2011). Where can I find it?

(I could find only the older one: [SQL 92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt))

Comment: @marc_s thanks for comment, please add as answer, to mark it as correct one. Well I expected this to be free.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to the ISO web site - you can search for `9075 2011` and you'll get 13 hits for the 13 parts of the standard that can be ordered from their online store:

http://www.iso.org/iso/home/search.htm?qt=9075%202011&sort=rel&type=simple&published=on

I don't know of any source where this standard would be available for free, unfortunately.

Comment: You are right: the standard's documents are not available for free. I not even the `sql1992.txt` is actually legal but apparently the committee doesn't care...

Comment: I don't get this. How are you supposed to adopt a standard if only to read it you need to pay CHF 178 (192 USD).. Absolute nonsense

Comment: *Part 1: Framework (SQL/Framework)* is available for free from the ISO website: [ZIP download](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c053681_ISO_IEC_9075-1_2011.zip).

Comment: The web page [Don't Tell Anyone: The SQL Standard is Public!](http://modern-sql.com/standard) by Markus Winand might be useful.

Comment: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9075:-1:ed-4:v1:en

Answer (score 2):

Reference from [Developer FAQ - PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#Where_can_I_get_a_copy_of_the_SQL_standards.3F) (some of them are broken, take remarks in 【】 symbol) :

> You are supposed to buy them from ISO/IEC JTC 1/SC 32 or ANSI. Search for ISO/ANSI 9075. ANSI's offer is less expensive, but the contents of the documents are the same between the two organizations.
>
> Since buying an official copy of the standard is quite expensive, most developers rely on one of the various draft versions available on the Internet. Some of these are:
>
> - SQL-92 [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt)
> - SQL:1999 [http://web.cs.ualberta.ca/~yuan/courses/db_readings/ansi-iso-9075-2-1999.pdf](http://web.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Eyuan/courses/db_readings/ansi-iso-9075-2-1999.pdf) 【404 Now, an alternative [SQL-99 Complete, Really -- SQL99](https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest//)】
> - SQL:2003 http://www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip
> - SQL:2011 (preliminary) http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip
> - No free copy of SQL:2016 appears to exist.
>
> ...
>
> Some further web pages about the SQL standard are:
>
> - http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/links/#standards
> - http://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html
> - [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql.html#syntax](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql.html#syntax) (SQL-92) 【404】
> - http://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/en/lokal/standards.pdf (paper) 【Redirect】

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with it.

If you want to own it (read it as many times as you want, carry it from one place to another, etc.) then you have to buy it as @marc_s mentioned.

If you want to get familiar with what is written in it then try searching for libraries that has the document. Some libraries definitely has the document you need and will allow you to read it. If you cannot find any of such libraries then it is probably worth visiting the library of Lithuanian Standards Board (LST) in Lithuania:
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=lt&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lsd.lt%2Findex.php%3F-1525317889